# Remove/delete embeds from a message

Tags: java, discord-jda

I made my own Discord bot for my Minecraft server with an order system (for developers).

When you react on the ,essage for the order, the message should edit to `The Order was claimed by @Discord`

And that works, but I also want to remove the EmbedMessage, that was sent with.

But there doesn't exists a method like `message.removeEmbeds()` or `message.deleteEmbeds()`.

So, how is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for [MessageAction](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/requests/restaction/MessageAction.html) explains:

> When updating a Message, unset fields will be ignored by default. To override existing fields with no value (remove content) you can use override(true). Setting this to true will cause all fields to be considered and will override the Message entirely causing unset values to be removed from that message.
> This can be used to remove existing embeds from a message:
>
> `message.editMessage("This message had an embed").override(true).queue()`